# Is there a function to get a circle object color in javafx?

Tags: java, javafx

I am working with circle objects in a gridpane and I have to check to color of the circle object by clicking it. For example if it's blue, do some stuff, if it's red, do other stuffs.

Comment: All concrete instances of [`Shape`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/17/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/shape/Shape.html) have `getFill()`.

Comment: Thank. Sorry for dummy question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**get shape color with mouse event**

[image: color shape]

you can get it with `getFill()` and change it with `setFill()`  method and provide a concrete Paint object as argument.
this is a single class javafx app you can try .
mouse event will print getFill as string
App.java

```
public class App extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        Paint defaultColor = Color.AQUA;
        Paint clickColor = Color.YELLOWGREEN;

        Circle circle = new Circle(50, clickColor);
        circle.setOnMouseClicked(e -> {
            if (circle.getFill().equals(defaultColor)) {
                circle.setFill(clickColor);
            }else{
            circle.setFill(defaultColor);}
        System.out.println(circle.getFill().toString());

        });

        Scene scene = new Scene(new StackPane(circle), 200, 200);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.setTitle("changing fill color");
        stage.show();

    }
}
```