# Multiple Rectangle setOnMousePressed doesn't work in JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx

I am currently working on a project that works with a 5 by 5 rectangular grid. Whenever a rectangle is clicked, it should change from black to red. However, only the bottom right rectangle provides this function. [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cKL9W.png)

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;


public class Example {
   private ArrayList<ArrayList<Tile>> list = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Tile>>();
   public AnchorPane anchorPane = new AnchorPane();

    public Example() {
       for (int c = 1; c < 6; c++) {
           ArrayList<Tile> temp = new ArrayList<Tile>();
           for (int r = 1; r < 6; r++) {
               Tile tempTile = new Tile();
               tempTile.stackPane.setPrefHeight(c*200);
               tempTile.stackPane.setPrefWidth(r*200);
               tempTile.column = c-1;
               tempTile.row = r-1;
               temp.add(tempTile);
               anchorPane.getChildren().add(tempTile.stackPane);
           }            
           list.add(temp);
       }
   }


   public class Tile{
       StackPane stackPane = new StackPane();
       int column;
       int row;
       Tile() {
           Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(100,100,Color.BLACK);
        rect.setOnMousePressed(e-> {
               rect.setFill(Color.RED);
          }); 
           stackPane.getChildren().addAll(rect);
           
       }
   }

}
```

Comment: pressed != clicked .you need `setOnMouseClicked()`

Comment: follow this for onClick event [changing color to shape](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72331758/is-there-a-function-to-get-a-circle-object-color-in-javafx/72332117#72332117)

Comment: The last stack pane you create (the one that is 1200x1200) will cover everything else, preventing mouse events from propagating to the other rectangles. Make all the stack panes the same size as the rectangles (or just omit them entirely and use just the rectangles), and put them in a grid pane, or something similar

Answer (score 4):

Your `Title` panes are be laid out on top of each other, so only the last one can respond to a mouse event (as it's blocking the others).

Personally, I can't see any good reason that you should be using additional panes this way, instead, just add the `Rectangle`s to the base pane, for example...

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javafx.application.Application;
import static javafx.application.Application.launch;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class App extends Application {

    private ArrayList<ArrayList<Tile>> list = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Tile>>();
    public AnchorPane pane = new AnchorPane();

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        stage.setTitle("Stackoverflow");

        for (int c = 1; c < 6; c++) {
            ArrayList<Tile> temp = new ArrayList<Tile>();
            for (int r = 1; r < 6; r++) {
                Tile tempTile = new Tile(c - 1, r - 1);
                temp.add(tempTile);
                pane.getChildren().add(tempTile);
            }
            list.add(temp);
        }

        Scene scene = new Scene(pane);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.sizeToScene();
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();
    }

    public class Tile extends Rectangle {
        private int column;
        private int row;

        public Tile(int column, int row) {
            super(column * 100, row * 100, 100, 100);
            setFill(Color.BLACK);
            setStroke(Color.BLUE);
            setStrokeWidth(1);
            this.column = column;
            this.row = row;
            setOnMousePressed(e -> {
                System.out.println(column + "x" + row);
                setFill(Color.RED);
            });
        }

        public int getRow() {
            return row;
        }

        public int getColumn() {
            return column;
        }
    }
}
```

Of course, if you really wanted to use `Pane`s to do this, you could just use a `GridPane` instead, for example...

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javafx.application.Application;
import static javafx.application.Application.launch;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.Background;
import javafx.scene.layout.BackgroundFill;
import javafx.scene.layout.Border;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderStroke;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderStrokeStyle;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderWidths;
import javafx.scene.layout.CornerRadii;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class App extends Application {

    private ArrayList<ArrayList<Tile>> list = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Tile>>();
    public GridPane pane = new GridPane();

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        stage.setTitle("Stackoverflow");

        for (int c = 1; c < 6; c++) {
            ArrayList<Tile> temp = new ArrayList<Tile>();
            for (int r = 1; r < 6; r++) {
                Tile tempTile = new Tile(c - 1, r - 1);
                temp.add(tempTile);
                pane.add(tempTile, c - 1, r - 1);
            }
            list.add(temp);
        }

        Scene scene = new Scene(pane);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.sizeToScene();
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();
    }

    public class Tile extends Pane {
        private int column;
        private int row;

        public Tile(int column, int row) {
            this.column = column;
            this.row = row;

            setPrefSize(100, 100);
            setMinSize(100, 100);
            setMaxSize(100, 100);
            setBorder(new Border(new BorderStroke(Color.BLUE, BorderStrokeStyle.SOLID, CornerRadii.EMPTY, BorderWidths.DEFAULT)));
            setBackground(new Background(new BackgroundFill(Color.BLACK, CornerRadii.EMPTY, Insets.EMPTY)));
            setOnMousePressed(e -> {
                setBackground(new Background(new BackgroundFill(Color.RED, CornerRadii.EMPTY, Insets.EMPTY)));
            });
        }

        public int getRow() {
            return row;
        }

        public int getColumn() {
            return column;
        }
    }
}
```